# Не понимаю в чем ошибка и почему происходит такое поведение? Почему-то при использование grid, все ломается из-за второго элемента

Tags: html, css

Получается так, что из второго элемента цвет заднего фона, как будто вытекает (это видно на картинке). Возможно я слабо ориентируюсь в технологии, но все же интересует, как решить такую проблему. Ниже вставлю код блока.

```css
.records {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
grid-template-rows: 150px;
:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #80d8ff;
}
:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #82b1ff;
}
:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: #b388ff;
}
:nth-child(4) {
    background-color: #ea80fc;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="records__item">
            <div class="records__circle"></div>
            <div class="records__spec">
                12000+
                <br> 
                Business
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="records__item">
            <div class="records__circle"></div>
            <div class="records__spec">
                60000+
                <br>
                Downloads
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="records__item">
            <div class="records__circle"></div>
            <div class="records__spec">
                30000+
                <br>
                Free Installs
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="records__item">
            <div class="records__circle"></div>
            <div class="records__spec">
                40000+
                <br>
                Pro Users
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: Сетка grid]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у Вас не фон "вытекает", а в том, что у вас цвет верха сетки и фон этого элемента одинаковы - везде `#82b1ff`

Вы можете изменить цвет одного из двух - и все будет так, как Вы задумали.

Comment: Так вот в чем дело. 
Благодарю за ответ, буду пробовать

Comment: Если Вы просматривайте свой html файл в хроме, советую скачать расширение ColorZilla для проверки цветов. Работает как обычная пипетка.